# Casperjs command line cookies aren't accepted

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Nothing happens when I execute this code using the command prompt

```
$casperjs login.js --cookies-file=D:\temp\cookies.txt
```

The cookies file is never created ?!

Anyone can help?

Comment: maybe this helps: [casperjs --web-security=no --cookies-file=/tmp/mycookies.txt myscript.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781604/casperjs-web-security-no-cookies-file-tmp-mycookies-txt-myscript-js-did-not/45793841#45793841) Best regards rikku47

Answer (score 0):

Just two things to check:

- Is there any security restriction for that path ?
- Test with a basic website like google. Maybe your Login.js does nothing.

Comment: @Mostafa Mahmoud please give your thoughts to the above answer.. if it's a good answer reward it and if it's lacking please explain why