# casperjs --web-security=no --cookies-file=/tmp/mycookies.txt myscript.js did not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Hi for me the command did not working:

```
$ casperjs --web-security=no --cookies-file=/tmp/mycookies.txt myscript.js
```

(just copied from the documentation of casperjs: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html#casperjs-native-options)

I have created the cookie file from another script. Now I want to implement the cookies into the second script. But the above command did not work.

What I want, is to implement the cookies before the first page invoke.

And yes the cookies are still alive, bcause if I use this in the second script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
phantom.cookies = JSON.parse(fs.read("pathToTheCookies"));
```

it works. But I want to do it with the command line, because I want to give the path with arguments.

Thanks.

OS: Windows 10

Best regards.

rikku47

Answer (score 0):

I got it. My solution for Windows (my OS Windows 10) is a command line like this:

```
casperjs --cookies-file="""pathIncludeWhiteSpaces""" """scriptPathIncludeWhitspaces""" """argument1""" """argument2"""
```

In the arguments you can put paths too. Just wrape them with six quotes

**"""AnyArgumentAndOrPath"""**

and it should work. the official solution from the documentation did not work for me, if I use cookies.

With other word if I use this command:

```
casperjs --cookies-file=\"pathIncludeWhiteSpaces\" \"scriptPathIncludeWhitspaces\" \"argument1\" \"argument2\"
```

it work for the first time to write the cokkie file. But if I let it read, it do nothing (it looks like).

Here is the part of the documentation:

> Hint
>
> You may need to wrap an option containing a space with escaped double
>   quotes in Windows. –foo=\”space bar\”

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html#casperjs-native-options

Best regards rikku47